# Placing Model Outputs in Created folders

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, export

I have created a model that created 6 output categories and each of those is exported to SHP, KML, and CSV. My model also creates the folders I want each of those exports to be places in. Below is an example of how my folders will be structured.

```
Tool Outputs
  Category A
      KML
      SHP
      CSV
  Category B
      KML
      SHP
      CSV
```

I want to know how to link my exports to their corresponding folders created in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable substitution in the output path for each of the outputs.  Read blog post and help http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/02/20/10-things-i-wish-i-had-known-about-model-builder-before-i-started-using-it/

In your case, perhaps make the category identical to the folder naming convention.